# Is there shortcut for weight paint add/subtract in blender 3.0+?

Tags: shortcut, weight-paint-mode

Is there shortcut for weight paint add/subtract in blender 3.0+ ?

I am still using 2.79 for rigging cuz of that..

Is there any add on for this or blender never gonna add them? :C

@Yousuf Chaudhry
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: not that I know, it would be good to invert the effect with Ctrl, as it works in Sculpt mode

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Edit > Preferences > Keymaps > Name > 3D View > Weight Paint to check the shortcuts or add some:[image]

[image]

Comment: I did check there but there is no option for assigning shortcut for add/subtract/multiply.  
There are index assign part that can change to draw or avg or blur but not for draw mode in detail. 2.79 had those option. looks like 2.8+ completely remove them?

Comment: @SunnySun show me the preferences of 2.79 which had the options... Also open the dropdown there.

Comment: I added the photo up there. I did checked the dropdown but there is no option like 2.79 does. From the photo, you can see number that can be assign. Those number contain ID add or subtract or multiply. from 2.8 Their own ID got removed and they can't be assign to shortcut anymore. I wonder they have some special ID numbers for 2.8+